# How to throw an exception in server and catch it in client c++?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if I could send an exception from server and receive it in the client.
Here's my server:

```
void MyServer::on_new_message(int identifier, string message) {
    if(/*some condition for message*/)
      throw BadIO();
}
```

and here's my client's main:

```
int main(){
try{
          cin>>c;
          socket.send(c);
          socket.receive();
        }
            catch(BadIO& exp)
        {
          cout<<exp.what()<<endl;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

after runing this code I get:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'BadIO'
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's your exception.

Comment: How are the client / server communicating? This question is missing a *lot* of necessary details.

Comment: Your client and server are on different processes, and likely will be on different machines. A robust solution would have the server serialize the exception into some format the client can read, upon which the client would then throw the appropriate exception.

Comment: Your messaging protocol will need a way of transmitting the exception event. The client can then throw an appropriate exception in its end of the protocol.

Comment: @GillBates no actually that's not my error code :D I got it from C...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart locally,i enter some port adrees for client and then by opening another terminal,i pass the port adress to server.

Comment: @AndyG I'm not sure if I got you right but I run them on the same pc at the same time.

Comment: @RichardHodges how can I transmit the exception event from server to client?

Comment: @Ghazal.S catch the exception on the server, send a message to the client. On the client, interpret the message and throw a corresponding exception.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.

The exception needs to be serialized in the server, just like any other object you pass between processes. Have a special message for exceptions, so that `socket.receive` can detect it, deserialize the exception and throw it in the client.

Comment: Got it.So I realize I can't directly send a throw exception by the server's send protocol unless i use an intermediate string in between.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Ghazal.S Right, there is no magic here unfortunately, roll up your sleeves.